# ASP.NET MVC 3 Jquery alert not being rendered

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am making a start on including Jquery in my mvc application.

The following code is present:

**Home Controller:**

```
namespace Tutorial.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
       [HttpGet] // /Home/Index/
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           ViewBag.Title = "Javascript";
           return View();
       }

    }
```

}

**_Layout:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">            </script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

**View:**

```
Content
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/init.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**init.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Document Ready");
});
```

Yet when I launch it no alert appears.
I have looked at the source code:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Content
    <script src="/Scripts/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the javascript file rendered:

**init.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

});
```

As you can see the alert function is missing. Any idea why it is not being redered?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: Ive updated my code with joe's responce but same problem occurs**

Comment: See the dev tools error console.

Comment: @user1487087 $ is defined or not defined. check it in browser console.

Comment: One thing you should look at - especially in MVC, you should not have relative references to static content, since the path the browser thinks you're at isn't always the same as the path you think you're at (think about `/` vs. `/Home` vs. `/Home/Index` vs `/Home/Index/2` etc. all referring to the same view). You can do `<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/init.js")"></script>`, or in MVC4 (not sure about 3), you can just do `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/init.js"></script>`. This will resolve the relative path appropriately when the page is rendered.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to render this

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/init.js"></script>
```

**after** jquery reference and you're doing it before as far as I understand from your code. You could use a script section for that.

Default `_Layout` already comes with this section in place. On your page, you should have.

```
@section Scripts {
   <script type = "text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/init.js"></script>
}
```